# Problema back-up base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server, ssms, microsoft-sql

no puedo hacer back-up ni restaurar las copias que hice antes, lo hago a través de Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Me aparece el siguiente error

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Backup failed for Server 'servidor-prueba'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.17008.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20471

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

To accomplish this action, set property Devices. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=16.100.17008.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.PropertyNotSetExceptionText&LinkId=20471

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Antes funcionaba todo con normalidad, pero desde hace un mes no puedo hacer back-up. El servidor lo revisamos y estaba lleno, liberamos espacio, pero aún así continúa con el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado.
Se verificó en el servidor, y mi usuario no tenía permisos de administrador de la base de datos.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)